# UIButton is not displaying below the TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a view-controller, to which I add a tableView, and a “Done” Button.

I’m able to add the tableview to my view controller successfully, but my “Done” button does not display.

The tableview is supposed to display at the top of the view, and the done button is supposed to display at the bottom, beneath the tableview.

Only the tableview displays and it takes up the whole screen.

Can you please advise what the issue is? Is there something wrong with my constraints?

Thanks!

```
@interface MyView : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end

@interface MyView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *doneButton;

@end

@implementation MyView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [_tableView registerClass:UITableViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
    [_tableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [_tableView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor constant:10],
        [_tableView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor constant:-10],
        [_tableView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor constant:20],
        [_tableView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor]
    ]];
    self.view.largeContentTitle = @"Title";
    self.title = @"Title";
    _doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    _doneButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_doneButton];
    [_doneButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [_doneButton.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor],
        [_doneButton.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_tableView.trailingAnchor],
        [_doneButton.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_tableView.bottomAnchor],
        [_doneButton.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor]
    ]];

    //[_tableView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_doneButton.topAnchor].active = YES;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Here's a screenshot, attached. The tableview appears in white and pink, while the view (which contains that tableview) is yellow. This yellow viewcontroller is presented on top of another view controller...

Attached screenshot, tableView contained inside a Yellow View - Done button is not displaying:

[image]

Comment: You have constrained the bottom of your tableview to the bottom of the superview. You don't want that. You also have a redundant constraint from the tableview bottom to the button top. You have previously constrained the top of the button to bottom of the tableview

Comment: Just use the View Debugger. You'll see the problem immediately.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 - I removed the constraint from the bottom of the tableview to the bottom of the superview, and my button shows up. Thanks!

Comment: As said by matt, next time, you can check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html it might help you debugging ;)